# How to wrap content in html in a Rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I want to wrap some content in HTML in a Rails 3 helper so that in my view I can do this:

```
<%= rounded_box do-%>
  <%= raw target.text %>
<% end -%>
```

I have a helper method that looks like this:

```
def rounded_box(&block)
  str = "<div class='rounded_box'><div class='rounded_box_content'><div class='rounded_box_top'></div>        
  str << yield
  str << "<div class='rounded_box_bottom'><div></div></div></div>"
  raw str
end
```

The way I have it now returns the content properly wrapped in the HTML string, but not before rendering any erb in the rounded_box block (e.g. in this case the target.text is rendered twice, once wrapped, once not).

Is there a better way to do this? For simplicity, I'd like to avoid using content_tag, but if that's the only/best way I can do that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Call `capture` on the block instead of `yield`:

```
def rounded_box(&block)
  str = "<div class='rounded_box'><div class='rounded_box_content'><div class='rounded_box_top'></div>"        
  str << capture(&block)
  str << "<div class='rounded_box_bottom'><div></div></div></div>"
  raw str
end
```

Comment: Yep, that's how I would do it.  Had to look at rails source to figure it out though when I wanted to :(  Stackoverflow is overpowered =p

Comment: Hey guys, this is cool. I have a stupid question - I tried including a module  from the application controller with the above helper method in it and I'm getting undefined method `capture' for #<BirdsController:0x000001020c7f80>. Where did you define your helper?

Comment: got it, just used ActionView::Base.send(:include) instead and it works.

Comment: Make sure the capture block call has the & before block - capture(&block) and not capture(block). As someone new to ruby/rails that detail made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<%= raw target.text %>` to `<% raw target.text %>`, and ERB should handle the rest. You don't need to explicitly output the result of the intervening ERB tag, because it's been handled by the helper.

Comment: That's incorrect if he correctly uses the capture() method that Jakub suggested.  yield will do some very funky things - like double-rendering some things when you didn't mean to.

Comment: Yeah, the only thing this changes is that the target.text, rather than showing up twice, shows up no times :) The above solution worked fine. Thanks though.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't even consider `capture` vs `yield` ... sorry!